# Adding 2 numpy nd.array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have to numpy.ndarray  A & B which are of the following shape 
A=(500000,784),B =(500000,).I need to add these 2 arrays in a way that the array B , which has labels gets added as the 785th column in the array without changing any sequence in its row- wise data. 
i.e, A becomes of shape  (500000,785).

Answer (score 0):

```
np.append(A.T,[B.T], axis=0).T
```

For example:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,9,11]])
B = np.array([4,5,3,6])
np.append(A.T,[B.T], axis=0).T
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  5],
       [ 7,  8,  9,  3],
       [10,  9, 11,  6]])
```